# Facebook Oauth Login

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I'm developing a site on the LAMP stack.  I'm using the Facebook SDK for PHP.  Everything works but when the user is prompted to login, they are presented with lots of options to do other things.  Like this:

[image: complex facebook login]

They can change languages, initiate a forgot password request, etc.  Ideally I would like a Facebook login screen that only has the username (email), password and a submit button. Like this:

[image: simple facebook login]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, there is not.